# Xamarin.Forms DatePicker Time

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm using the Xamarin Forms Date Picker and it is working fine. But the picker only displays Month, Day and Year. I need to also add the ability for the user to set a time. Is there any built in way to do that, or can I subclass the Picker and add it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xamarin Forms has a separate TimePicker control.  There does not appear to be a single integrated DateTime control.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely missed that!

Comment: How can you change the background color of date and time picker ? It does not reflected in Android.

Comment: @SoftSan Checkout overwriting the Android theme using Styles.xml. I am sure there is an entry you can add in there to change the datepicker colors/styles. Let us know what you find that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a control called DateTimePicker. It smashes the DatePicker and TimePicker controls together. This is because a lot of the time, we are dealing with DateTimes together - not separately. The control is in this library Adapt.Presentation. Samples with two way binding can be found inside the repo .

https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git

I will soon be maintaining the NuGet package but I'm a bit slow to update it so it's best to get the code and compile it currently.